# YouTube Data API (v3) : how many request credits should be associated with checking if lifestream is live?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api

I created YouTube Data API (v3) API key to check from the web page if my livestream is active, so that in case it's not I show alternative backup YouTube video. The problem is that within the first hour or so of testing it generated 5000K + requests and used up 50%+ of 10000 quota. I suspect that it is not normal. The help reference does not list livestream while states that it does. How many credits is such check supposed to take? Maybe I am doing something wrong? The current volume of "quoted requests" the calls generate makes the usage potentially cost prohibitive.

Checking prior questions/responses I found the following:
Basically, there is some quota each day for using YouTube Data API v3. Posting a video costs 1600 units. Getting some information about a video cost 1 unit.

That kind of implies that checking if livestream is active or not should not cost 1600, but rather should cost 1 credit, please help.

I implemented YouTube Data API (v3) key and I make request, get response, parse response, it works well. just the rate of quota usage seem to be really excessive. I hope that there are ways to reduce it, in case it's correct. I think I only made a handful of calls. Maybe 20-30.

Comment: To what endpoint do you currently make requests?

Comment: www.mydomain.com checkLivestream.php sends request to YouTube Data API to fetch information about a YouTube channel's livestream status using a PHP script

Comment: What you tell me is not an endpoint, [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) is an endpoint for instance.